# React Diagrams Links not straight

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, user-interface

I am using the `react-diagrams` library to make an app with. However, I am a bit annoying by the links not adjusting automatically to be straight. Here is an example of what I am talking about.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ih0pd.png)

Is there any way to fix this? It is really annoying to look at and deal with

Comment: Can you share the code example or something? Are you using RightAngle Link instead of a normal one? The normal link should for the curved line without any break as shown in image.

Comment: @MehulThakkar Yes I am using AngledLink but I am wondering if there is some kind of NormalLink that can automatically adjust the link position to always be straight between two Nodes

Comment: You can use the normal link. Refer to the code example in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Probably that is happening due to the usage of `AngledLink` as mentioned by you in the comment. You can use simple link instead of AngleLink.

Here's the working example at [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-diagram-simple-linking-cm8pv?file=/src/App.js). You can try moving/dragging the nodes in any way and this won't break the link line.

### App.tsx

```js
import createEngine, {
  DiagramModel,
  DefaultNodeModel
} from "@projectstorm/react-diagrams";
import * as React from "react";
import { CanvasWidget } from "@projectstorm/react-canvas-core";
import { DemoCanvasWidget } from "./DemoCanvasWidget";

export default () => {
  //1) setup the diagram engine
  var engine = createEngine();

  //2) setup the diagram model
  var model = new DiagramModel();

  //3-A) create a default node
  var node1 = new DefaultNodeModel({
    name: "Node 1",
    color: "rgb(0,192,255)"
  });
  node1.setPosition(100, 100);
  let port1 = node1.addOutPort("Out");

  //3-B) create another default node
  var node2 = new DefaultNodeModel("Node 2", "rgb(192,255,0)");
  let port2 = node2.addInPort("In");
  node2.setPosition(400, 100);

  // link the ports
  let link1 = port1.link(port2);

  //4) add the models to the root graph
  model.addAll(node1, node2, link1);

  //5) load model into engine
  engine.setModel(model);

  //6) render the diagram!
  return (
    <DemoCanvasWidget>
      <CanvasWidget engine={engine} />
    </DemoCanvasWidget>
  );
};
```

### DemoCanvasWidget.tsx

```js
import * as React from "react";
import styled from "@emotion/styled";
import { css, Global } from "@emotion/react";

export interface DemoCanvasWidgetProps {
  color?: string;
  background?: string;
}

export const Container = styled.div<{ color: string; background: string }>`
  height: 100%;
  background-color: ${(p) => p.background};
  background-size: 50px 50px;
  display: flex;

  > * {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }

  background-image: linear-gradient(
      0deg,
      transparent 24%,
      ${(p) => p.color} 25%,
      ${(p) => p.color} 26%,
      transparent 27%,
      transparent 74%,
      ${(p) => p.color} 75%,
      ${(p) => p.color} 76%,
      transparent 77%,
      transparent
    ),
    linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      transparent 24%,
      ${(p) => p.color} 25%,
      ${(p) => p.color} 26%,
      transparent 27%,
      transparent 74%,
      ${(p) => p.color} 75%,
      ${(p) => p.color} 76%,
      transparent 77%,
      transparent
    );
`;

export const Expand = css`
  html,
  body,
  #root {
    height: 100%;
  }
`;

export class DemoCanvasWidget extends React.Component<DemoCanvasWidgetProps> {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Global styles={Expand} />
        <Container
          background={this.props.background || "rgb(60, 60, 60)"}
          color={this.props.color || "rgba(255,255,255, 0.05)"}
        >
          {this.props.children}
        </Container>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

If this is not your use case then you can refer to [this link](https://projectstorm.cloud/react-diagrams/?path=/story/simple-usage--canvas-drag) to find the best-suited example for your use case.

Comment: I'm sorry but appears to be an error when I run the code

Comment: Please click on the codesandbox link. Don't run it here. I have added code here for samples only. The execution can take place at codesanbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-diagram-simple-linking-cm8pv?file=/src/App.js